# Adding in assembly info configuration for log4net into .NET Core xunit project

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration, log4net

We are creating an XUnit test project in .NET Core 2.1 for an application that is .NET Framework 4.6.1 so we can test the changes made for features and technical debt cleanup. We've run into a snag with one of our more important unit tests that caused us to add in Log4Net NuGet package into the unit test project. With it added in we get the following error:

```
Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'log4net.ILog log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.String)'.
```

With a bit of research, I found that the error is caused by a lack of configuration for the project missing the XMLConfigurator. Normally, in .NET Framework, you would edit the AssemblyInfo.cs file with the line (according to previous stack overflow answers):

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```

However, we don't have an AssemblyInfo.cs file, any app.config file, or json configuration files. In .NET Core, do I need to add in this configuration? Do I add it (and how) into the .csproj file? We don't have a single entry point for the project because it just is xunit tests which is something some people are talking about it. Do I need another configuration file? I can't seem to find a coherent or a complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: Did you came up with any solution, Ross?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue.
What you can do is manually load/bind the config file, below is the 4 line code

(1) Add the Log4net.config file to your solution
(2) Add following to your solution

```
    ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
string DirPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo(Path.Combine(DirPath, "log4net.config")));

log.Debug("This is a Log4Net Debug message");
log.Info("This is a Log4Net Info message");
log.Warn("This is a Log4Net Warning message");
log.Error("This is a Log4Net Error message");
log.Fatal("This is a Log4Net Fatal message");
```

Comment: What is logRepository in the example above?